# Does this lemma have a name or where can I find a proof?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, terminology

[Does the lemma at the bottom of this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=iaeUqc2yQVQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false) have a name? Or could someone give me an idea of where I can find a proof?

In case you can't access the link:

> **Lemma $\ \ $** *If $g$ is of class $C^k(k\geqslant2)$ on a convex open set $U$ about $p$ in $\Bbb R^d$*, then for each $q\in U$,
>
> $\displaystyle\begin{array}{rl}(1) & g(q)=g(p)+\sum_{i=1}^d\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r_i}\left|\right._p\big(r_i(q)-r_i(p)\big)\\&\qquad\ +\sum_{i,j}\big(r_i(q)-r_i(p)\big)\big(r_j(q)-r_j(p)\big)\int_0^1(1-t)\dfrac{\partial^2g}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}\left|\right._{(p+t(q-p))}dt.
> \end{array}$
>
> *In particular, if $g\in C^\infty$, then the second summation in $(1)$ determines an element of $F_p^2$ since the integral as a function of $q$ is of class $C^\infty$.*

Comment: Do you have the book? The citation [31] apparently gives a proof of this lemma. (Unfortunately the bibliography isn't publicly available)

Comment: It looks like an variant of Taylor expansion.

Comment: I doubt this has a name, this is really (the first order) Taylor series expansion along the line segment joining $p$ and $q$ whose error is expressed in the (integral) form of a [Lagrange remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html). Since the function is $C^2$, you just express the directional derivatives of the function in terms of partial derivatives.